# Javascript - On click, check if element has an attribute with value

Tags: javascript, onclick, addeventlistener

The button

I want to get it to work with an event listener like this one:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
console.log(e.target);
    if (e.target.hasAttribute('data-a-target="popout-chat-button"')) {
            console.log('popout button');
    }
});
```

```html
<button data-a-target="popout-chat-button" data-test-selector="popout-button">Popout</button>
```

I can't check the value with hasAttribute, what would be the best approach to do so.

Comment: What about [getAttribute()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `e.target.getAttribute` to get the attribute value of the target element. Then compare that with the value of the attribute you expect in the `if` condition:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
    if(e.target.getAttribute('data-a-target') === "popout-chat-button"){
        console.log('popout button');
    }
});
```

```html
<button data-a-target="popout-chat-button" data-test-selector="popout-button">Popout</button>
```

> The getAttribute() method returns the value of the attribute with the specified name, of an element.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> element.getAttribute(attributename)

Comment: Yea that's it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @oban_internet: Because it's a `data-` attribute, modern browsers will let you do `e.target.dataset.aTarget == "..."`

Comment: @CrazyTrain Thanks for telling me. Might be useful in the future.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Yea i wanted to mark it but i had to wait 9 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

> [.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset): The HTMLElement.dataset property allows access, both in reading and writing mode, to all the custom data attributes (data-*) set on the element, either in HTML or in the DOM. ...

Instead of:

```
e.target.hasAttribute('data-a-target="popout-chat-button"')
```

you can simply write:

```
e.target.dataset.aTarget == "popout-chat-button"
```

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  console.log(e.target.dataset.aTarget);

  if(e.target.dataset.aTarget == "popout-chat-button"){
      console.log('popout button');
  }
});
```

```html
<button data-a-target="popout-chat-button" data-test-selector="popout-button">Popout</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can user `getAttribute` function. It returns the value of attribute if it exists otherwise return null.

```
if(e.target.getAttribute("data-a-target") === "popout-chat-button") {
     // attribute exists and value is equal to what you want...
}
```